# The meaning of "me gustas tú"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

What does *me gustas tú* mean in Spanish? I was told it means *I like you.*

I'm currently learning Spanish, and  was wondering why "Me gustas tú" = "I like you" and not "You like me." The verb ends in -as, so I was taught that the -as ending represents the *tú* form, so why does it mean what it does?

Comment: In Spanish, the verb "gustar" works just the opposite as it does in English (i.e., the roles of subject and object are inverted). The Spanish equivalent of "to like" works the same way the verb " to please" does in English. To say "I like you" we literally say "Me you please" ("you please me"). More here: [How to use “gustar”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/how-to-use-gustar)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I like you is "me gustas tú" or "tú me gustas" in Spanish. Usually, this in the context of love feelings towards a girl or boy.

Answer (score 0):

If you translated it literally it would be "You please me".

see [gustar](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/gustar.htm) on study spanish, where they go into some detail on just this verb.